# Create an outlook task from SSIS

Tags: ssis, outlook

I am using BIDS (SQL 2005) to send an email via the send Email task. I need to convert this to a task which can be added to outlook and do this unattended. Is there anyway of doing this programmatically using a script task or the CozyRoc Mail Plus task maybe by manipulating the headers of a normal email. As this is just SMTP there must be some way of making an email look like an outlook task.

http://www.cozyroc.com/ssis/send-mail-task

NB: This must run unattended so I cannot use the script to create an object in outlook which the user then confirms.

Edit: I should also mention I am trying to target Outlook 2007

Comment: Help me understand, why are you attempting to use Outlook, a mail client, to send this message? The bog standard Send Mail Task talks natively to Exchange, the mail server, to create and send email?

Comment: All the examples use outlook to create a task as Outlook 2007 apparently does not support ICS VTODO format. To be clear it is a task I want to send, not an email